# Broken layout in "We really like this job for you."

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I believe the email shouldn't look like on screen (I'm using Thunderbird). Instead of putting mail content below the Stack Overflow logo now it's on the right. The footer with "You're receiving this message because you are opted in to Stack Overflow emails about special jobs." text looks fine again - it's centered, so the only problem is the whole job block.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your bug report.  This issue was a regression in the email layout, which we have now fixed.

Comment: I can confirm now is fine (I've just received an email)